# Why can't you give a bracha to yourself?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, hashkafah-philosophy

I didn't find anywhere people giving brachas to oneself. We find in Tanach people giving brachas to others. It seems one can't give a bracha to oneself. Why not?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.29.18?lang=bi

Answer (score 1):

This may be similar to the question asked and answered in the Talmud [Berachot 5b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=5b&format=pdf):

> רבי חייא בר אבא חלש על לגביה רבי יוחנן אמר ליה חביבין עליך
> יסורין אמר ליהמלא הן ולא שכרן אמר ליה הב לי ידך יהב ליה
> ידיה ואוקמיה רבי יוחנן חלש על לגביה רבי חנינא אמר ליה חביבין עליך יסורין אמר ליה לא הן ולא שכרן אמר ליה הב לי ידך יהב ליה ידיה
> ואוקמיה אמאי לוקים רבי יוחנן לנפשיה  אמרי אין חבוש מתיר עצמו מבית האסורים
>
> R. Hiyya b. Abba fell ill and R. Johanan went in to visit him. He said to him: Are your sufferings welcome to you? He replied: Neither they nor their reward. He said to him: Give me your hand. He gave him his hand and he raised him.
>
> R. Johanan once fell ill and R. Hanina went in to visit him. He said to him: Are your sufferings welcome to you? He replied: Neither they nor their reward. He said to him: Give me your hand. He gave him his hand and he raised him. Why could not R. Johanan raise himself? — They replied: The prisoner cannot free himself from jail.
>
> ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_5.html#PARTb))

Particularly if the Talmud here is referencing a metaphysical phenomenon, it would simply be that one’s metaphysical capabilities don’t necessarily extend to oneself.

Comment: I was thinking about this concept.. . I just wasn't sure.. that would mean you can't bless yourself with richness for this reason..

Answer (score 1):

[image]

aruch hashulchan 215 why you dont say omen after your own brocho. That seems to be the reason you also cant give yourselves berochos.

Answer (score 0):

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.12.2?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.12.2.3&lang2=bi) in the beginning of parshas Lech Licha writes:

> והיה ברכה. הברכות נתנות בידך, עד עכשיו היו בידי, ברכתי את אדם ואת נח ואותך, ומעכשיו אתה תברך את אשר תחפוץ.

My translation:

> The ability to give blessings is given to you. Until now, it was in my hands, I blessed Adam, I blessed Noach, and you. From now on you will bless whomever you choose.

According to this we can suggest the following. The ability for a human to give a bracha is a power derived from Hashem's ability to give a bracha. Inherently, Hashem cannot give himself a bracha as He lacks nothing. The receiver of this ability cannot have more power than the source of this ability and is therefore limited to blessing others.

Comment: We find in brachos 7a that Hashem asked for a bracha by Rabbi Yishmael ben Elisha and he blessed Hashem.

Comment: I also bless Him multiple times a day, and I assume you do too. What I meant is the type of bracha that Hashem gives is fundamentally different than the bracha a human gives. And the type of bracha that a human receives is fundamentally impossible to say applies to Hashem. That's why some people translates the baruch in brachos as being a mention of Hashem's being blessed, and not an act of filling I something that was missing ch'v.

Comment: boruch is a present verb but is not an active one. It means hashem is blessed. This type of verb is like tsorua or chosum where the second letter of root has an 00.

Comment: @interested That is the poplar modern approach, see Artscroll for instance. Rav Hirsch for one example wrote against that idea.

Comment: What I wrote and gave examples is part of dikduk. One cant change dikduk. I forgot the term they used thanks!

Comment: @interested The grammarians refer to this form as בינוני פעול (passive participle)

Comment: @interested Than it is indeed noteworthy that a famous scholar of grammar had a differing opinion. I'll try to find it, iirc it was in his commentary on the siddur.

Comment: Exactly, meaning you don't really bless God. However in the gemara brachos 7a  he really did bless God..

Comment: @Shlomy You would need to source that his bracha was different according to those who say we don't actually bless Hashem. If anything his Bracha was a chidush to even be called a bracha, yehi rayzon lifanecha etc is a much more passive sounding bracha saying the words baruch atah.

Comment: As you already explained most learn baruch ata means you are the source of blessing...  in brachos he was saying something should change. That's like the bracha one gives a person.